# Finding a desired point in a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

There is problem, I reduce it to a question as below:

In a connected undirected graph, edge weight is the time to go from one end to another. some people stand on some vertex. Now, they want to meet together, find a place(vertice) that within certain time T, all the people will arrive this assembly point. Try to minimise this T.

More information if you need for margin cases: No negative edge; cycle may exist; More than one person can stay on the same vertice; vertice may have no person; undirected edge, weight measures both u->v or v->u; people start from their initial location;

How to efficiently find it? Should I for every node v, calculate max(SPD(ui, v)) where ui are other people's locations, then choose the minimum one among these max times? Is there a better way?

Comment: Normally edge weight is defined from one vertex to another that is directly connected to it. Please also tell where the people start - are there one at each vertex, or can there be more than one at a vertex, can one or more vertex have no people? Are there any cycles? More information is needed to find a solution. I think we also need the definition of the graph to eliminate edge cases such as where there are only two vertices and one path.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be done within a polynomial runtime bound as follows. In a first pass solve the [All-Pairs Shortest Path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) to obtain a matrix with corresponding lengths of shortest paths for all vertices; afterwards iterate over the rows (or columns) and select a column where the maximum entry of all indices on which users are located.

Comment: This method will always return result in the set of {users' locations}, however the assembly point can be vertex without user, right?

Comment: No, the approach would not necessarily return a vertex on which users are located. Consider for instance the graph with indices `{0,...,3}`; visualize the graph as a circle with `0` in the middle and `1,...,3` in equal distance on the circumference. The distance from `0` to every other vertex woudl be `1` and the distance from every node in `1,...,3` to every other node in `1,...3` would be `10`. The users would be locatd on the circle. The approach above would return a value of `3`, which would correspond to a solution where all users meet in the middle at vertex `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by making parallel Dijkstra from all vertices, and stopping when sets of visited nodes intersect in one node. Intersection can be checked by counting. Algorithm sketch:

```
node_count = [1, 1, ...] * number_of_nodes  # Number of visited sets node is in
dijkstras = set of objects D_n performing Dijsktra's algorithm starting from node n
queue = priority queue that stores tuples (first_in_queue_n, D_n).
        first_in_queue_n is next node that will be visited by D_n
        initialized by D_n.first_in_queue()
while:
  first_in_queue_n, D_n = queue.pop_min()
  node_count[first_in_queue_n] += 1
  if node_count[first_in_queue_n] == number_of_nodes:
    return first_in_queue_n
  D_n.visite_node(first_in_queue_n)
  queue.add( D_n.first_in_queue() )
```